How to disable first space in HTML input?
Consider a simple Vue component with text input (link).
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const msg = ref('')

function onInput(e) {
  let value = e.target.value;
  if (value === ' ') value = '';
  msg.value = value;
}
</script>

<template>
  <input :value="msg" @input="onInput" />
</template>

I want to disable first space in this input, i.e. if a user inputs space then the inputfield should remain empty. But it doesn't work. I guess it happens because Vue checks that msg doesn't change and rejects component render.
My next attempt is to force render the component (link).
<script setup>
import {getCurrentInstance} from 'vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'

const msg = ref('')

const instance = getCurrentInstance();

function onInput(e) {
  let value = e.target.value;
  if (value === ' ') {
    value = '';
    msg.value = value;    
    instance?.proxy?.$forceUpdate();
    return;
  }
  msg.value = value;
}
</script>

<template>
  <input :value="msg" @input="onInput" />
</template>

It works, but with limits. My project has a big tree of components and $forceUpdate updates current component only without children.
I also tried to re-render the whole sub-three with changing key on the component, but in this case I lose input's focus.
To sum up, it seems that I miss something. I can't believe that such simple task requires weird workarounds. Please help me to find a simple and "best practice" way to disable first space in html input.
P.S. React version works as expected.
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  function onInput(e) {
    let v = e.target.value;
    if (v === ' ') v = '';
    setValue(v);
  }

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <input value={value} onInput={onInput} />
    </div>
  );
}


Isn't trim or some CSS enough in this case?

@kissu trim works the same way as the logic in my case. CSS? Well, also looks like a dirty hack)

trim is quite more flexible and safer overall. Also, it's meant for that specific usage. Depending on what you want to achieve, either trim the value just before it's send to the backend or use some CSS if you care about the visuals. As a whole, I would just skip touching to the default behavior and let the user see the given space that they wrote, why trying to hack the default behavior of HTML? If the idea is to restrict actual usage of anything but a string character, then it's more of a validation topic that could use HTML (with input's pattern) or maybe even VeeValidate.

Re-rendering the whole tree will indeed be expensive and will not bring a lot of benefits if you already have a busy component.

@kissu I provided a very basic example just to highlight the problem without extra details. In my project I have a complex input component for a user to input full name. The component has placeholder, input pattern, auto suggestions and so on. And to make it work as expected I need to block space as a first character. I will use $forceUpdate to solve my problem, but I'm really shocked that such simple problem is solved with weird hacks only.

This is not really a Vue problem, more of what happens when you try to control the default behavior of HTML inputs within a JS context. I would again, just let the default behavior of letting people being able to input a space without taking control over it. A minimal reproducible example is very welcome and a great initiative. Having something more complex in real-world doesn't change my take on the topic tho, either trim it before piping it to your auto-suggestions/etc or adapt your logic there to work with a whitespace (should be more than feasible).

Can't you use v-model instead of :value?

@fOURP v-model is pretty much just sugar syntax for :value. Also this doesn't solve the "issue" here.

@kissu but this IS Vue problem. Two-way data binding Vue algorithm is broken here because the model is empty string (''), but input's value is one space (' '). I can fix it with ugly $forceUpdate. But it means that I'm doing Vue's work manually by saying "Hey, Vue, you missed an update here, do your job".

If you v-model the msg ref, it will properly reflect an empty space as shown here. You want to disallow people to type a space, which is an unrelated concern and not Vue's job.

Yes, simple examples work as expected. But if you dig deeper you can find edge cases where synchronization breaks.

@kissu I added React version of my example (see original question) and it works like a charm without weird hacks. So, it's Vue's issue.

No reason for the reactivity to break out of the blue. React example is also quite irrelevant because both frameworks do not work the same way. If you try to write Vue code as you do in React, expect this to not work properly indeed. One uses fine-grained reactivity with Proxies while the other one does its own thing regarding re-rendering and hooks. I recommend you to use your (Vue) devtools to try to narrow down where the issue is coming from. Also, try to not "translate" React into Vue, but rather understand how the framework works by reading the official documentation.

Based on your code: don't react to the input event. It's too late. React before the input event occurs. And filter out that space character.
This will save the application a lot of unnecessary calculations (msg=" ", then msg="").
<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  const msg = ref('')

  const filterFirstSpace = e => {
    const isEmpty = !e.target.value.length
    const isSpace = /\s/.test(e.data)

    if (isEmpty && isSpace) {
      e.preventDefault()
    }
  }
</script>

<template>
  <input
    :value="msg"
    @beforeinput="filterFirstSpace"
  />
</template>


You can handle the @keydown event to detect if the first entered symbol is a space and prevent entering if so.
Here is an example:
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const msg = ref("");

function onInput(e) {
  msg.value = e.target.value;
}

function preventLeadingSpace(e) {
  if (msg.value.length === 0 && e.key === " ") {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <input :value="msg" @input="onInput" @keydown="preventLeadingSpace" />
</template>



You should use a regular expression to remove the first whitespace character from the string.


  const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

        createApp({
            setup() {
                const inputValue = ref('');

                const removeFirstSpace = () => {
                    // 使用正则表达式去除第一个空格
                    inputValue.value = inputValue.value.replace(/^\s/, '');
                };

                return {
                    inputValue,
                    removeFirstSpace
                };
            }
        }).mount('#app');
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-CN">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vue 3 Input 示例</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>输入示例</h1>
        <input type="text" v-model="inputValue" @blur="removeFirstSpace" placeholder="输入一些内容">
        <p>你输入的内容是: {{ inputValue }}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>




Sounds very much overkill.

Thanks for your example, but it doesn't fix my problem. I can insert space as a first character in the input field.
